# if statement always print text

Tags: c#, razor

I need to print all the code under my question

if there is data in `@store.GuaranteePolicy` print all the `<tr>`. If there is no data, then print nothing.

No matter if there is data in or not in `@store.GuaranteePolicy`, then "Payment" is always printet, but why?

I said that if (store.GuaranteePolicy is different than null, then print)

The if statement is working with this:

- If there is data in `store.GuaranteePolicy` everything is printed perfect
- If there is no data in `store.GuaranteePolicy` the text is not printed, *BUT* the word *Payment:* is printed. So the whole `<tr>` is printed even if it is not true?

  ```
  @if (store.GuaranteePolicy != null) { 
  <tr>
      <th class="small-12 large-6 columns first">
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <th width="300">
                      <p class="text-left small-text-left"><strong>Payment:</strong></p>
                  </th>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </th>
      <th class="small-12 large-6 columns last">
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <th width="300">
                      <p class="text-left small-text-left">
                          <span>@store.GuaranteePolicy</span>
                      </p>
                  </th>
                  <th class="expander"></th>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </th>
  </tr>
  }
  ```

Comment: Have you debuged your application and looked what the value of store.GuaranteePolicy is when you think it should not be printed?

Comment: I don't know what it is but is there a list of zero items or something similar? Default values?

Comment: maybe try to use Count() method if it is a collection and compare to 0

Comment: Could that GuaranteePolicy be "empty" instead of null? Try [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If GuaranteePolicy is a collection try this:

```
@if(store.GuaranteePolicy != null && store.GuaranteePolicy.Count > 0)
{

}
```

if string:

```
@if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(store.GuaranteePolicy))
{

}
```

and so on...